# JavaFX Media Player seek() method being inaccurate

Tags: javafx, media-player

I'm developing an application that takes many different media inputs and synchronizes them through a common timeline. The specific medias being played are supplied in plug-ins. In particular, I'm working on a plug-in that handles a video input.

The problem arises when I try to update the currentTime of the video player.

What happens is that the new currentTime (which has to be modified through the seek() method) is *very* innacurate in relation to the value submitted. Here is the code in question:

**Controller**

```
package com.emcoder.facialplugin;

import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaView;
import javafx.stage.FileChooser;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.media.Media;
import javafx.util.Duration;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Path;

/**
 * @author manacho
 */
public class MainController {

    @FXML
    MediaView mediaView;

    @FXML
    Button addSourceBtn;

    @FXML
    Label label;

    @FXML
    TextField input;

    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

    public Pane getLayout(){
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(FacialPluggin.class.getResource("layout.fxml"));
        fxmlLoader.setController(this);
        Pane pane = new Pane();
        try{
            pane = fxmlLoader.load();
        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        addSourceBtn.setOnAction((event) -> addVideoSource());
        input.setOnAction((actionEvent -> {
            seek(Double.parseDouble(input.getText()));
        }));

        return pane;
    }

    protected void addVideoSource(){
        // Mostramos el menú de elección de archivos
        FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
        Stage stage = new Stage();
        fileChooser.setTitle("Elija el archivo");
        var dialogResult = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(stage);
        // Si el resultado es no nulo, abrimos la elección como media y se lo asignamos al media player
        if (dialogResult == null) return;
        Path videoPath = dialogResult.toPath();
        Media media = new Media(videoPath.toUri().toString());
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(media);
        mediaView.setMediaPlayer(mediaPlayer);
    }


    public void play(){
        this.label.setText("Playing: \t" +mediaPlayer.getCurrentTime());
        this.mediaPlayer.play();
    }


    public void pause(){
        this.mediaPlayer.pause();
        this.label.setText("Pause: \t" + mediaPlayer.getCurrentTime());
    }


    public void seek(double millis){
        this.mediaPlayer.seek(Duration.millis(millis));
        Platform.runLater(() -> {
            this.label.setText(String.valueOf(millis) + "\t" + mediaPlayer.getCurrentTime() + Duration.millis(millis));
            this.mediaPlayer.seek(Duration.millis(millis));
        });
    }
}
```

**layout.fxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.media.*?>

<Pane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/16" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <VBox alignment="TOP_CENTER" spacing="20.0">
         <children>
            <MediaView fx:id="mediaView" fitHeight="400.0" fitWidth="600.0" />
            <Button fx:id="addSourceBtn" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Add source" />
            <Label id="label" fx:id="label" />
            <TextField fx:id="input" />
         </children>
         <padding>
            <Insets bottom="15.0" top="15.0" />
         </padding>
      </VBox>
   </children>
</Pane>
```

**MainClass (that extends Application)**

```
package com.emcoder.facialplugin;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;

public class FacialPluggin extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        MainController mainController = new MainController();
        Scene scene = new Scene(mainController.getLayout(), 320, 240);
        stage.setTitle("Hello!");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```

The layout is very simple: just a Pane with a VBox that contains a MediaView, a Button and a Label.

As you can see, I also show the input time (which is calculated from the position of the timeline cursor), the value of the MediaPlayer, and the value the former recieves once the input time is transformed into a Duration value. Here are some examples of the values this label shows:

[The values differ by a lot!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ow0Dn.png)

[Another example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s56Bp.png)

I've read other questions with similar problems, although no concrete solution has been given. If anyone could point me in the right direction I'd greatly appreciate it.

PS: this behaviour persists even if I don't use a Platform.runlater() call.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just guessing here, but probably `seek()` doesn't update the `currentTime()` until another frame is rendered. Have you tried calling `seek()` immediately, and updating the label in `Platform.runLater()`? Alternatively, register a "one-shot" listener with the `currentTimeProperty` and update the label the next time `currentTime` changes.

Comment: [mcve] please ..

Comment: thanks @James_D for your comment! I tried what you suggest, both the listener and updating the label at a different instance. It appears this behaviour is related to some bondary values - as in it jumps from 0[ms] to 800[ms], and from 800[ms] to 2000[ms], ignoring anything in between. I'm working on a better minimal reproductible example so you can see it yourself

Comment: Hi @kleopatra! I modified the code blocks to make it as good a minimal reproducible example as I could, given that it's part of another more complex system.